# how to set "Accrept snmp packets from these hosts" with IPv6 address

Tags: windows, ipv6, snmp

As I understood SNMP service on windows vista and above supports IPv6.
I would like to set the accepted hosts with IPv6 address, how is it done?

Using the SNMP service configuration of windows there are an option to set accepted hosts for snmp packets but when trying to set IPv6 format addresses it fails, how can I set IPv6 hosts?

thanks.

[image: SNMP service configuration window windows7]

Comment: I managed to add the accepted host IPv6 address directly to the registry and it worked, but is there a way to that using the UI? because it looks like not so good workaround.